# How to handle 401 for all Kendo UI objects in one place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, unauthorized

I have to deal with Kendo UI objects that call backend scattered all around the app. I would like to create single handler for all 401 responses (Unoauthorized) for Kendo UI objects so I can use refresh token.

**Question:** How to handle all error responses in single place for Kendo UI objects?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI uses jQuery's Ajax behind the scene to perform all it's ajax requests, so you will be able to register a callback with [`jQuery.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) to handle any ajax error. Note that other ajax calls made with jQuery will trigger that event as well.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, xhr, data, error)
{
    if (xhr.status == 401) // Unauthorized error
    {
    }
});
```